# Fuzzing big endian code in little endian environment with libfuzzer

Tags: c, fuzzing, libfuzzer

I am trying to fuzz a part of code written for big endian MIPS architecture using libfuzzer.

I have run libfuzzer under a Debian little endian machine and segmentation faults are issued. I think that the results are not a 100% trustworthy. How to use libfuzzer with an emulator for big endian architectures? Is this possible? Are there any other techniques for testing big endian code in little endian architectures by using fuzzing?

Comment: I guess you want to tell libfuzzer the range of acceptable values, and it doesn't understand big-endian ranges?

Comment: If it is just 1 field could you define that field as 4 bytes, and tell the fuzzer the range of values for the uppermost byte, and let it put any value in the lower bytes? EG if the largest value is 8 million, then in big endian, the first 2 bytes would be free, the third byte would be 0-122, the last byte would be zero.

Comment: I thought something else. Have you ever used qemu with a MIPS big endian Linux and libfuzzer? I think it is more close to what I am looking for. What do you think?

Comment: Execpt what I described there is little-endian - sorry! In big endian, to represent 0-8million,  the first byte would be zero, the second byte would be 0-122, and the last 2 would be 0-255.

Comment: Sorry, I've not used fuzzers enough in anger to point to options that would address your issue directly, which is why only comments.

Comment: No problem Gem.I was looking for a workable 64 bit MIPS big endian img for Qemu since libfuzzer is available only for 64 bit archs!

Answer (score 0):

You could cross-compile your software to big-endian MIPS on your host machine, and then use QEMU user-mode emulation. In this mode, QEMU runs a single process on the emulated CPU, eliminating all the emulated hardware. Instead, it merely translates system calls to the host **kernel**, so the process accesses all the host files, networks, etc. -- just like if your host CPU would get the ability to execute MIPS instructions -- it now can mess with your host files etc. too, you have been warned. :)

I'm not familiar with specifically `libfuzzer`, but this setup should suffice to at least **validate** already found crashes (supposing one can trust that QEMU simulates MIPS CPU realistically enough). AFAIK `libfuzzer` is an in-process fuzzer, so unlike AFL, the fuzzed process should not face some problems with communicating to the separate fuzzer process using shared memory, etc.